# Autofac Registration & Resolution Confusion

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

Having trouble determining how to register two instances of a concrete class with different parameter arguments that later need to resolve to different services. In my app I am outputting data from a model to a text file:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<SqlConnection>()
    .WithParameter("connectionString", ConnectionString)
    .As<IDbConnection>();

builder.Register(c => new FileStream(".\cat.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    .As<FileStream>();
// how would I also register another file stream like this so that it can be used later on?
//builder.Register(c => new FileStream(".\dog.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
//   .As<FileStream>();

// and would I need to alter this, or would it be able to resolve multiple streamwriters?
builder.Register(c => new StreamWriter(c.Resolve<FileStream>()) { AutoFlush = true })
    .As<StreamWriter>();
builder.Register(c =>
{
    var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(c.Resolve<StreamWriter>(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
});

var container = builder.Build();

using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var cnn = container.Resolve<IDbConnection>();
    var catRecords = cnn.Query<CatModel>("select * from dbo.Cat")
    container.Resolve<CsvWriter>().WriteRecords(catRecords);
    // how do I get the correct resolution here?
    //var dogRecords = cnn.Query<DogModel>("select * from dbo.Dog")
    //container.Resolve<CsvWriter>().WriteRecords(dogRecords);
}
```

How do I register and resolve correctly to incorporate the two files correctly? Do I needed to use a delegate factory? Keyed registration? I have read through the documentation quite a lot, but I'm having trouble figuring out what fits here.

Comment: [There's an FAQ for this.](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)

Comment: @TravisIllig thanks! That example provides different concrete class implementations of an interface vs mine which is the same concrete class `FileStream`, just different parameters values supplied. It seems using the "option 3: keyed services" seems appropriate for this scenario? Is there an implementation available from option 2? Just trying to wrap my head around Autofac and how to use it appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Keyed Services

Implementation with [keyed services](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html?highlight=keyed%20services#option-3-use-keyed-services)

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<SqlConnection>()
    .WithParameter("connectionString", ConnectionString)
    .As<IDbConnection>();

builder.Register(c => new FileStream(".\cat.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    .Keyed<FileStream>("cat");
builder.Register(c => new FileStream(".\dog.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
   .Keyed<FileStream>("dog");

builder.Register(c => new StreamWriter(c.ResolveKeyed<FileStream>("cat")) { AutoFlush = true })
    .Keyed<StreamWriter>("cat");
builder.Register(c => new StreamWriter(c.ResolveKeyed<FileStream>("dog")) { AutoFlush = true })
    .Keyed<StreamWriter>("dog");

builder.Register(c =>
{
    new CsvWriter(c.ResolveKeyed<StreamWriter>("cat"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}).Keyed<CsvWriter>("cat");
builder.Register(c =>
{
    new CsvWriter(c.ResolveKeyed<StreamWriter>("dog"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}).Keyed<CsvWriter>("dog");

var container = builder.Build();

using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var cnn = container.Resolve<IDbConnection>();
    var catRecords = cnn.Query<CatModel>("select * from dbo.Cat")
    container.ResolveKeyed<CsvWriter>("cat").WriteRecords(catRecords);
    var dogRecords = cnn.Query<DogModel>("select * from dbo.Dog")
    container.ResolveKeyed<CsvWriter>("dog").WriteRecords(dogRecords);
}
```

### Named Services + Autofac Module

Combining the solution above with an [Autofac module](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/modules.html) to help adhere to DRY coding practices. Swapped [keyed services](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#keyed-services) for [named services](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html?highlight=named%20services) since that was more the intent. As a side note, CsvWriter (part of CsvHelper) automatically flushes the buffer when using `WriteRecords`. You will get better performance by setting `AutoFlush = false` on the StreamWriter.

```cs
public class FlatFileModule : Module
{
    protected readonly string _filePath;
    protected readonly string _recordType;

    public FlatFileModule(string FilePath, string RecordType)
    {
        _filePath = FilePath;
        _recordType = RecordType;
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(c => 
            new StreamWriter(_filePath, false, Encoding.UTF8) 
            { 
                AutoFlush = false 
            })
            .Named<StreamWriter>(_recordType);

        builder.Register(c => 
            new CsvWriter(
               c.ResolveNamed<StreamWriter>(_dataType),
               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            )
            .Named<IWriter>(_recordType);
    }
}

...

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<SqlConnection>()
    .WithParameter("connectionString", ConnectionString)
    .As<IDbConnection>();

builder.RegisterModule(new FlatFileModule(@".\cat.txt", "Cat"));
builder.RegisterModule(new FlatFileModule(@".\dog.txt", "Dog"));

var container = builder.Build();

using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var cnn = container.Resolve<IDbConnection>();
    var catRecords = cnn.Query<CatModel>("select * from dbo.Cat")
    container.ResolveNamed<IWriter>("Cat").WriteRecords(catRecords);
    var dogRecords = cnn.Query<DogModel>("select * from dbo.Dog")
    container.ResolveNamed<IWriter>("Dog").WriteRecords(dogRecords);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that there isn't a "right way" or a "clean way" to do this. It's more about "what works," and it appears the module approach is a balance of "works" and "reasonably maintainable" so that's as good as it gets. You could make the stuff in the module "Load" method an extension method on ContainerBuilder, but it'd still be the same thing - several parameterized, named registrations that get made all at once - not better or worse, and not more "right" than any other way to go. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: @TravisIllig I appreciate the guidance. Sometimes its hard to know when you've reached that point of "as good as it gets" when learning these frameworks, especially when you look through the elegant Autofac project code examples. You get in the habit of thinking there must be a better way.